# how to replace a value with that value + constant

Tags: text-processing, sed, numeric-data

I have a file which has variables from G1 to G229. I want to replace them with G230 to G469; how I can do that? I tried this bash script but it didn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for num in {1..229}
  do
  echo G$num
  N=$(($num+229))
  echo G$N  
  sed -i -e 's/$G$num/$G$N/g' file
done
```

Comment: wouldn't 229 + 229 be 458, not 469? Simple keyboard-typo?

Comment: yes, my apologize, it is 458!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` solution. Maybe it too tricky and unoptimal, but it works. As an experiment :).

It do all replacements in the one `sed` call by executing the one, big command sequence, generated by `printf` and `paste` usage. I wanted split this command to the multiline for readability, but couldn't - it stops working then. So - the oneliner:

```
sed -i -r "$(paste -d'/' <(printf 's/%s\\b\n' G{1..229}) <(printf '%s/g\n' G{230..458}))" file.txt
```

It is converting to the following `sed` command:

```
sed -i -r "s/G1\b/G230/g
s/G2\b/G231/g
s/G3\b/G232/g
s/G4\b/G233/g    
...
s/G227\b/G456/g
s/G228\b/G457/g
s/G229\b/G458/g" file.txt
```

**Explanation**

1. `sed -i -r "$(`
2. `paste -d'/'` - joins left and right parts (which are generated in 3,4 steps) by the slash - `/` and the result is this: `s/G1\b/G230/g`
3. `<(printf 's/%s\\b\n' G{1..229})` - makes left parts of the `sed` substitute command. **Example:** `s/G1\b`, `s/G2\b`, `s/G3\b`, so on.

   - `\b` - Matches a word boundary; that is it matches if the character to the left is a “word” character and the character to the right is a “non-word” character, or vice-versa. **Information** - [GNU sed, regular expression extensions.](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions)
4. `<(printf '%s/g\n' G{230..458})` - makes right parts of the `sed` substitute command. **Example:** `G230/g`, `G231/g`, `G232/g`, so on.
5. `)" file.txt` - input file.

---

#### Testing

**Input**

```
var G1 = value;
G3 = G1 + G2; 
G3 = G1 + G2
G3 = ${G1} + G2
var G2 = value;
var G3 = value;
G224 = G3 + G215;
G124 = G124 + G215;
G124 = G124 + G12;
var G4 = value;
var G5 = value;
var G6 = value;
var G59 = value;
var G60 = value;
var G156 = value;
var G227 = value;
var G228 = value;
var G229 = value;
```

**Output**

```
var G230 = value;
G232 = G230 + G231;
G232 = G230 + G231
G232 = ${G230} + G231
var G231 = value;
var G232 = value;
G453 = G232 + G444;
G353 = G353 + G444;
G353 = G353 + G241;
var G233 = value;
var G234 = value;
var G235 = value;
var G288 = value;
var G289 = value;
var G385 = value;
var G456 = value;
var G457 = value;
var G458 = value;
```

Comment: Thank you for your complet explanation! just the one line worked very well.

Answer (score 8):

That's more a job for `perl` (which GNU `sed` copied that `-i` from by the way):

```
perl -pi -e 's{\$G\K\d+}{
  if ($& >= 1 && $& <= 229) {
    $& + 229
  } else {
    $&
  }}ge' file
```

Note that it would also change `G0001` to `G230`. If you don't want that, you can change the `\d+` to `[1-9]\d*`.

With your approach, even if you fixed the quoting, that would rewrite the file 229 times and also not work as you'd wish.

A `s/\$G1/\$G230/g`, would change `$G12` to `$G2302`, and the next `s/\$G2/\$G231/g` would then change that to `G231302` (which the `s/\$G23/\$G252` would change to `G2521302` and so on).

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes in bash stop variable expansion so the following is looking for the literal `$G$num` to replace with the literal `$G$N`

```
sed -i -e 's/$G$num/$G$N/g' file
```

You want bash expansion to happen so you must use double quotes and escape any special characters manually:

```
sed -i -e "s/\$G$num/\$G$N/g" file
```

You can see the difference with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for num in {1..229}; do
  N=$(($num+229))
  echo '$G$num $G$N' vs "\$G$num \$G$N"
done
```

Produces

```
$G$num $G$N vs $G1 $G230
$G$num $G$N vs $G2 $G231
$G$num $G$N vs $G3 $G232
...
$G$num $G$N vs $G228 $G457
$G$num $G$N vs $G229 $G458
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I executed this code as Jeff said it gives very big numbers for example G2542130 for G1